RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 1
I am new to PyTorch and ML programming in general and I am facing an error while training a ResNet. I first downloaded a CIFAR-10 images from PyTorch datasets and rotated them using a random angle (four possible angles: 0,90,180,270). My ultimate goal is for my ResNet to predict the degree of rotation of my images. From the error, I found that my predictions have a different dimension compared to my ground truth values.
first five predictions:  tensor([[ 0.0683,  0.3461,  0.4453, -0.0036],
    [-0.6092,  0.2731,  2.5144,  0.0371],
    [ 0.3840, -0.0392,  0.0524,  0.4138],
    [ 0.3602, -0.1470, -0.5595,  1.3381],
    [-0.1769,  0.1314,  1.2383,  0.0638]], grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)
first five rotation labels:  tensor([2, 2, 2, 1, 3])

Below is the error trace:
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-8178c1e3d209> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train(net, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=45, decay_epochs=15,    init_lr=0.01, task='rotation')

<ipython-input-28-bb8773810582> in train(net, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs,   decay_epochs, init_lr, task)
     26             print("first five rotation labels: ",rotation_label[:5])
     27             curr_accum_total += rotation_label.size(0)
---> 28             curr_accum_correct += (predictions == rotation_label).sum().item()
     29 
     30             if i % print_freq == (print_freq - 1):

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 1

My code is in this link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CcEUtTTdF1i_wLzJh2le4Wmevio4CPJY?usp=sharing
I am still learning and any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Most likely your prediction tensor has shape [128, 4] and rotation_label tensor has shape [128,]. Basically, you should first take the argmax of prediction tensor first (by dim -1).

You are right, I took the argmax and it worked. Thank you!
